# What's an 'Exceptional' Geometry book that has 'Solutions' for beginners.

Tags: geometry, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am studying basic Geometry (English lang), and I am looking for an 'Exceptional' Geometry textbook.

If you can give a textbook that you've used (that would be more preferable) because I value how you've learned maths.

I honestly have problems with learning maths, and I am learning how to self-learn maths in the best way possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try looking at Schaum's Outline of Geometry any edition. Hundreds of solved problems. The entire Schaum's Outline series of books is designed for self-learners and beginners. In my experience, the best way to self-learn is to do lots of problems and look at how similar problems are solved. Schaum's Outline has solutions so you don't have to wonder how it is done.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you Somos!

Comment: This is more a comment isnt it?

Comment: OP asked a suggestion or a comment as an answer.... maybe reference request tag could be included.

Comment: Thanks Narasimham. I will add reference request tags in my future questions.

Comment: I subscribe to Somos's excellent piece of advice.